# Cancelling an Async Task In Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am trying to cancel an async task after a period of time. i have searched and found a lot of questions about this and all having the same answer like what i am doing below.

problem: after calling cancel, the webservice does not seem to cancel because it never reaches the onPostExecute.
please any help will be appreciated.

what i have tried:

after a certain period of time i call

class TimeOut that takes an asyncTask as its argument and performs the below:

```
if (task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING )
        {task.cancel(true);}
   if(task.isCancelled()==true)
            {
                Log.e(TAG,"TASK IS CANCELLED");
            }
```

and in my async class

```
@Override
    protected void onCancelled() {

        webServiceError=true;  //when timeout change it to true.(default false)
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.webserviceDownloadUserDataError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        int paramsTracker = 0;
        webServiceError = false;


        while(webServiceError==false) {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            String url = params[paramsTracker];
            paramsTracker = paramsTracker + 1;

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            int paramsCount = params.length;

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(paramsCount);
                for (int i = 0; i < (paramsCount - 1) / 2; i++) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "parameters: " + params[paramsTracker] + " - " + params[paramsTracker + 1]);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(params[paramsTracker], params[paramsTracker + 1]));
                    paramsTracker = paramsTracker + 2;
                }
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // execute http post request, call web service


                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                webServiceError = true;
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                try {
                    AppLogging(TAG, "Error in calling web service " + e.toString(), LogFileName.ErrorLogFilename);
                } catch (Exception a) {
                }
            }


            if (webServiceError == false) {

                int CNT = 0;
                try {

                    String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM TASKS";
                    Cursor cursor = MainActivity.myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            CNT = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CNT")));
                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    try {
                        AppLogging(TAG, "Error in Database error getting task count " + e.toString(), LogFileName.ErrorLogFilename);
                    } catch (Exception a) {
                    }
                }

                if (CNT == 0) {
                    String webServiceResponse = "";
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Getting web service response");
                        // get web service response
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        String content;
                        content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
//                  Log.d(TAG, "content: "+ content);
                        // parse XML response
                        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                        InputSource is = new InputSource();
                        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(content));
                        Document doc = db.parse(is);
                        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("string");
                        Element line = (Element) nodes.item(0);
                        webServiceResponse = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);



                        String patternForON = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT \\[.*?\\] O?((N)|(FF))\\s*?;";
                        Pattern rForON = Pattern.compile(patternForON);
                        Matcher mForON = rForON.matcher(webServiceResponse);
                        String webServiceResponseWithOutIdentityInsert = mForON.replaceAll("");

                        String patternForInsert = "\\bINSERT (?!INTO)";
                        Pattern rForInsert = Pattern.compile(patternForInsert);
                        Matcher mForInsert = rForInsert.matcher(webServiceResponseWithOutIdentityInsert);
                        String webServiceResponseWITHOUTINSERTALONE = mForInsert.replaceAll("INSERT INTO ");
                        String webServiceResponsePURIFIED = webServiceResponseWITHOUTINSERTALONE.replaceAll(";;", ";");
                        Log.d(TAG, "content: " + webServiceResponsePURIFIED);
                        ///////////END OF for removing queries that are not applicable in SQLITE

                        //FOR SPLITTING THE QUERIES AND PLACING EACH AT AN INDEX IN contentArray ARRAY
                        //String contentArray [] = webServiceResponse.split(";");
                        String contentArray[] = webServiceResponsePURIFIED.split(";");
                        Log.d(TAG, "contentArray length" + contentArray.length + ""); //GETS THE NUMBER OF QUERIES
                        pd.setMax(contentArray.length); //SETTING THE PROGRESS DIALOG (MAX PROGRESS)

                        for (int i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++) {
                            // add the downloaded data to the local database
                            String query = contentArray[i];
                            try {
                                AppLogging(TAG, "Queries Downloaded splitted and purified\n query " + i + " :" + contentArray[i], LogFileName.LogFilename);
                            } catch (Exception l) {
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, "query: " + query);
                            // if query contains "getdate()" replace with DATETIME('now'), to render the query executable in sqlite
                            query = query.replace("GETDATE()", "DATETIME('now')");

                            try {
                                MainActivity.myDataBase.execSQL(query); //EXECUTE QUERY
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                                try {
                                    AppLogging(TAG, "Error in performing query: " + query + "\nError: " + e, LogFileName.ErrorLogFilename);
                                } catch (Exception a) {
                                }
                            }

                            //Log.d("Initialize database, HTTPRequestGetUserData ", query);

                            publishProgress();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        webServiceError = true;
                        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                        try {
                            AppLogging(TAG, "Error:  " + e.toString(), LogFileName.ErrorLogFilename);
                        } catch (Exception a) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
           if (isCancelled()) return "0";
        }
        return "1";
    }
```

Comment: it did not do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Android AsyncTask documents, after calling `cancel()` on AsyncTask it won't call `onPostExecute()` instead it will call `onCancelled()`. So the flow is desired.

Now as per documentation here in, your code

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

       while(webServiceError=false) {
                 .....//calling webservice
             if (isCancelled()) return "0";
        }
      return "1";
}
```

And now your onCancelled() looks like, with String parameters

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled(String object) { // Here object should be 0

    webServiceError=true;  //when timeout change it to true.(default false)
    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.webserviceDownloadUserDataError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (pd.isShowing()) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }
    super.onCancelled();
}
```

Now in this method argument `object will be 0`. And don't worry both methods `onPostExecute()` and `onCancelled()` will run on Main UI thread.

Now what I suggest you is, create a private method which you want to execute from `onPostExecute()` and `onCancelled()` with String parameters.

Comment: can you please help me, if(isCancelled) is not being called after calling cancel(true) if you want me to post the doinbackground method i will

Comment: @user3703305 i posted it

Comment: i am calling cancel after a timertask finishes (i.e 45 seconds) and after calling i check isCancelled() and it returns true

Comment: also onPreExecute, i have a progressdialog where i call cancel(true) if back  button is pressed (setOnCancelListener)

Comment: after 45 seconds i check the status of the task in another class, if it is running i cancel it..il post the method i am using but this is its idea

Comment: Ok. Just change the code lines as per my above comment and also debug the `doInBackground()` for last line where execution hits after calling `cancel` on AsyncTask.

Comment: ok i will do that now, thank you so much for your patience and help

Comment: finally worked but i placed if (isCancelled()) return "0"; before  response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Comment: Actually, In your case your while loop condition should be combination of, `!webServiceError &&  !isCancelled()` and after while loop code block `if (isCancelled()) return "0"; else return "1";` will work as best practice.

Answer (score 0):

When you cancel a AsyncTask it will never hit the OnPostExecute procedure. It is mentioned here in the API Doc:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)